VSCODE ignore exports on package.json when using "src" folder inside of my package on turborepo/pnpm
I have a package my-package on my repo under packages/ folder setup with pnpm and turborepo.
When import files from my "apps" I end up doing something like this:
import { MyFile } from '@my-repo/my-package/MyFile'
Is there a way of using baseURL or rootDir or similar property on my packages to avoid having to type the "src" folder?
currently, on my package.json inside of my package I have the following:
  "exports": {
    "./*": "./src/*"
  },

This works on my next.js app, but VSCODE still gives me the following error "Cannot find module '@my-repo/my-package/MyFile' or its corresponding type declarations".

In the end i had to change my tsconfig.json inside of my apps/my-app and add the following
"compilerOptions": {
   "moduleResolution": "nodenext"
}

now it works.
VSCode is complaining about new things with other packages, but my main issue was solved at least ( :

do you need to have .js extension when importing even though its a .ts file?
